# Validation Display in Registration form with Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code in crudindex.php  if I enter password with length less than 6 characters error message is not showing using the span command.Required pattern is working. But messages using span command is not displaying ex : if i enter length less than 6 in password no error message displays

What is wrong in this code?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
$error=false;
if (isset($_POST) && (!empty($_POST))){
 $uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["uname"]);
 $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pwd"]);
 $cpwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["cpwd"]);
$password_error="";
$cpassword_error="";
if(strlen($pwd) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($pwd != $cpwd) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        # Register-button was clicked


$createsql1="INSERT INTO cruduser(id,username,password) VALUES
                             ('','$uname','$pwd')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$createsql1)) {
echo "Insert Successful in Table cruduser";
mysqli_close($con);
//Redirect because we need to consider the post request from crudadd.php
header( 'Location: crudaddusr.php' ) ;
//include ("crudadd.php");
}
else
{
die(mysqli_error($con));
}
}
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        # Login-button was clicked
session_start();
$SESSION['suname']=$uname;
$SESSION['spwd']=$pwd;
if ($uname=='admin' && $pwd=='admin') {
include('crudview.php');
}
else
{
header( "Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=$uname&spwd=$pwd");
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<!--DocType HTML -->
<! bootstrap link is downloaded from bootstrapcdn.com for css and js -->
<! col-mod-6 col-mod-offset are bootstrap related-->
<HTML>
<head>
<title>"Add records in CRUD Table"</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
<h2>Create The table CRUD</h2>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username : </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="uname"  required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Username"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password: </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="password" name="pwd"  required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Password"/>
<span class="error"><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error;?></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password : </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="password" name="cpwd"  required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
<span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($cpassword_error))  echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">

                <div class="col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
                   <button id="submit1" name="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
                  <button id="submit2" name="login" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The only reason the procedural interface exists is because the `mysqli` API was introduced in PHP 4.1 which did not have object-oriented support at the time.

Comment: What happens when you enter the password less than 6 characters in length? Does it leave the field empty?

Comment: No, If I enter char less than  6  its not leaving empty and goes to the next field confirm password.

Comment: Yesganesh, I suggest that you separate registration and login. There is to much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example to display your errors and prevent some security problems. I have removed the `required pattern` from your html. You didn't properly set errors. You can handle errors with php and display them. Plus you didn't use `action="path/to/handleform.php"`.

And your redirect should be in login: `header( "Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=".$uname."&spwd=".$pwd);`

There are 3 security problems here:

- [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). SOLUTION=> prepared statement
- [Password saved as plain text](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing). SOLUTION=> [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). SOLUTION=> input hidden with a token

  ```
  <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

  // Declare array for errors
  $error=array();

  //-----------------------------------------------------//
  //---------------------CSRF PROTECT--------------------//
  //-----------------------------------------------------//

  //generate a token/
  function generateToken( $formName )
  {   
      //secret_key change it
      $secretKey ='?@GEskki58668445744!Erpoejsj48';
     if ( !session_id() ) 
     {
         session_start();
     }
     $sessionId = session_id();
     return hash('sha512', $formName.$sessionId.$secretKey );
  }

  //check if the token is valid
  function checkToken( $token, $formName)
  {
     return $token === generateToken( $formName );
  }

  //Separate REGISTER AND LOGIN TO NOT BE CONFUSED//

  //-----------------------------------------------------//
  //---------------------REGISTRATION--------------------//
  //-----------------------------------------------------//
  if ( isset($_POST['register']) && checkToken( $_POST['csrf_token'], 'userFromRegistration' )  ) 
  {
      //if the username required
      if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/',$_POST['uname']))
      {
           $error['username'] = "Username must have alphanumeric characters ";
      }

      //if password has less than 6 characters
      if(strlen($_POST['pwd']) < 6)
      {
           $error['password'] = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
      }

      //if password does not match
     if($_POST['pwd'] !== $_POST['cpwd'] OR empty($_POST['cpwd']) ) 
     {
           $error['passwordmatch'] = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
     }

      //if empty error array
      if( !array_filter($error) )
      {
           //trim data
           $username = trim( $_POST['uname'] );

           // Hash you password, never save PASSWORD AS PLAIN TEXT!!!!!!!
           // MYSQL! : Allow your storage to expand past 60 characters (VARCHAR 255 would be good)
           $password = password_hash( $_POST['pwd'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

           //if the id is autoincremented leave id
           //----------USE PREPARED STATEMENT FOR SQL INJECTION---//

           $query = 'INSERT INTO cruduser (username, password) VALUES (?,?)';
           $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
           $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->close();
           $con->close();

           //Redirect because we need to consider the post request from crudadd.php
           header( 'Location: crudaddusr.php' ) ;
       }
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------//
  //------------------------LOGIN------------------------//
  //-----------------------------------------------------//
  if (isset($_POST['login']))
  {
       //what ever you want
       //Use password_verify() and session_regenerate_id() 
       //to compare passwords and to generate a session id to prevent session fixation.
        session_start();
        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

        //if you don't need it delete it
        $SESSION['suname']=$unmane;
        $SESSION['spwd']=$pwd;

        if ($uname=='admin' && $pwd=='admin')
        {
            include('crudview.php');
        }
        else
        {
            header( "Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=".$uname."&spwd=".$pwd);
        }
      } 
  ?>

  <!--HTMl PART-->
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>"Add records in CRUD Table"</title>
          <!-- bootstrap link is downloaded from bootstrapcdn.com for css and js -->
          <!-- col-mod-6 col-mod-offset are bootstrap related-->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="container"> 
          <div class="row">
              <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
              <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo generateToken('userFromRegistration'); ?>" required/>
              <h2>Create The table CRUD</h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username : </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['username'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?> ">
                      <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Username"/>
                      <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['username'])) echo $error['username'];?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password: </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['password'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?>">
                      <input type="password" name="pwd"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Password"/>
                      <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['password'])) echo $error['password'];?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password : </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['passwordmatch'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?>">
                      <input type="password" name="cpwd" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                      <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['passwordmatch'])) echo $error['passwordmatch'];?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
                     <button id="submit1" name="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
                     <button id="submit2" name="login" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Login</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
     </body>
  ```

Comment: Fine. Registrtion is fine and table insert is fine.
But When i made the changes in the Login and  after redirecting the crudeditusr.php
its not populating the data for the selected user and pwd.header( "Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=$uname&spwd=$pwd"); In crudeditusr.php I use get command $uname=$_GET['suname'];
$pwd=$_GET['spwd'];

Comment: I have update the answer, please l=take a look the login part: your header will not work. It must be `header("Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=".$uname."&spwd=".$pwd);`. The in the In crudeditusr.php, use `$uname=$_GET['suname']; 
$pwd=$_GET['spwd'];

echo $uname;
echo $pwd;` Let me know if it works.

Comment: I will try. Also when the  the password using $_GET will be normal string. But in the table its stored as hash. How to compare  the string and hash . Now I am checking this.

Comment: username and pwd is correct. But the id is not getting pickedup. $uname=$_GET['suname']; $pwd=$_GET['spwd']; 
$selsql = "SELECT * FROM cruduser WHERE username='$uname'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $selsql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($count == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    print "hashedPass = ${row['password']}";
    print "myPassword: " . $pwd;
    if(password_verify($pwd, $row['password'])){
        print "Password match";
        $id=$row['id'];
   } else
        print "The username or password do not match";
}

Comment: ` $uname=$_GET['suname'];$pwd=$_GET['spwd']; 
$selsql = "SELECT * FROM cruduser WHERE username='$uname'";$res = mysqli_query($con, $selsql); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res); if($count > 1){ echo "hashedPass :". $row['password'] ."</br>";  echo "myPassword :" . $pwd ."</br>";if(password_verify($pwd, $row['password'])){echo "Password match"."</br>"; $id=$row['id']; } else{  echo "The username or password do not match"."</br>";}` $count is $count>0. improved code.

Comment: No luck. Still "The username or password do not match". Any clue?

Comment: Test with a new password, this should work! I have tested it, it works. Anyways if my post helped you and was usefull please vote up and accept it as an accepted answer :).

Comment: just 2 doubts. 1. In the crudindex.php if anyone login with admin and pwd adminx  it should open crudview.php. When i made the changes in code  all the users pressing the login button it goes to crudview.php. Also the echo values are not showing. 2. why i need to regenarate session.id for login screen? code for 1 is below --//------------------------LOGIN as admin---------------------//

if ( isset($_POST['login'])) 
  {
    if ($_POST['uname']="admin" && $_POST['pwd']="adminx")
  {
echo $_POST['uname'];
echo $_POST['pwd'];

    $con->close();
    include("crudview.php");
  }
}

Comment: It is better that you ask another question.. post all your code and will see it  and see what is not working.

Comment: I asked another ?. subject : Redirection not working in php.

Comment: where is the link

Comment: //------------------------LOGIN as admin---------------------//

if ( isset($_POST['login'])) 
  {
    if ($_POST['uname']=="admin" && $_POST['pwd']=="adminx")
  {
echo $_POST['uname'];
echo $_POST['pwd'];

    $con->close();
  header ("Location: crudview.php");
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from this,

```
$pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pwd"]);
```

to this,

```
$pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["pwd"]);
```

You don't need to add `$con` to assign your password to another variable but it's better use the direct `$_POST` variable no need to assign it to another.

```
if(strlen($_POST["pwd"]) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just to `echo` the message with out the `if` condition? if not try it and let me know. Or add a else part to your `if` where you try to `echo` error if the `else` part executes then that means it's not setting your password variable.

Comment: echo outside if is working . echo inside if not working, Inside this  statement if ((isset($_POST)) && (!empty($_POST)))     its not working. But data is getting inserted which is inside the if statement.. Data is inserted with entered username, password.